# which kind of service to use in order to create a notification according to time (Android)

Tags: android

I have a database in which the user saves the things that he wants to do.In each thing he can set a date of expiration.the point is, I want to create a list(notification list) where the "things to do" that are going to expire will appear. for example the user wants to create a list with the things that are going to expire in two days. I have used the IntentService and pass with the intent the time that the user selects each time but i get nothing. do I have to use service or bound service in this case? thank you in advance

Comment: You can use "Alarm Manager" and "Broadcast Receiver".

Answer (score 0):

you can use [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) class to fire off events at given times and in these events you can use [NotificationManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html) to trigger the notifications.

See alarm manager example here:
[Alarm Manager Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example)

See notifications guide here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: well,I ve thought of these options but I decided to work on it this way. I need to have a list.I havent figures out the differernce between the bound service and a simple service,so thats why I ask if I have to use another type of service to run in background

Answer (score 0):

Use the AlarmManager technique as like,..

```
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, yearFromDB);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthFromDB);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dateFromDB);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourFromDB);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuteFromDB);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

Use PendingIntent for the Wake up at the Specific time and perform this Task..

```
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(), ObjPendingIntent);
```

You can get the to do list on the Particular Time, Read on the PendingIntents and Alarmmanager by the following links..

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

and

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html